# request definition in wadl file

Tags: jersey, wadl

Is there any way the wadl can tells the request type. For example the following PUT method expect a xml data type of "setBlockRequest", is there any way I can reference it to the xml schema(xsd file) to define the content of "setBlockRequest"?

This wadl is generated by Jersey.

```
<resource path="/appliance/{device_id}/update_multiple_values">
<param xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" name="device_id" style="template" type="xs:string"/>
<method id="setBlockValue" name="PUT">
<request>
<ns2:representation xmlns:ns2="http://wadl.dev.java.net/2009/02" xmlns="" element="setBlockRequest" mediaType="application/xml"/>
</request>
</method>
</resource>}
```

Answer (score 1):

yes, there is. See http://www.w3.org/Submission/wadl/#x3-40001.3 (<grammars> tag).

Jersey now generated it automatically for you but only for cases where your type is annotated with JAXB annotations. (This is valid since Jersey 1.13 if I remember correctly, so you might want to give it a try).